# Missing assumption in MA estimation

Tags: estimation, least-squares, moving-average

Assume we observe a $MA(1)$ process for which it is known that the mean is zero. Based on a series of length $3$ , we observe $Y_1 = 0, Y_2 = 1$ and $Y_3 = 0.5$. Find the least-squares estimate of $\theta$.

We know that $$Y_t=\varepsilon_t+ \theta \varepsilon_{t-1}$$
so $$0=\varepsilon_1+ \theta \varepsilon_0  $$
$$1=\varepsilon_2+ \theta \varepsilon_1  $$
$$0.5=\varepsilon_3+ \theta \varepsilon_2 $$
Since we don't know $\varepsilon_t$, the design matrix cannot be inverted to perform least squares here. Am I understanding something wrong here ? Is there an assumption the problem forgot to tell ?

Comment: OLS cannot be used for estimating parameters of an MA model because the regressors (the lagged error terms) are unobservable. Perhaps some other estimator based on least squares (nonlinear LS?) could be used instead.